# Why won't this button remove this image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to practice my coding.  I've created an experimental webpage.  I have a picture of my face here.  I put a button below to remove my picture by setting the image's display property to "none."  However, nothing I try seems to work.  Why is this?  Here is all my code, because I have no idea where the problem could lie.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        body 
        {
            background-color: wheat;

        }

        .name:hover
        {
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }


        h1 {
        width: 500px;
border: 20px outset brown;
padding: 20px;
background-color: gold;
color: goldenrod;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
        }

        img {
            height: 500px;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DENNIS MARKHAM'S FUNSITE</h1>
    <br>
    <p>Hi, this is <span class = "name"> Dennis</span>, and I'm creating this website just for fun.  And
    I guess for practice too.</p>
    <p>As you can see, my name highlights when you scroll over it.  Isn't that cool?
        Well I think it is. </p>
    <p>I think this could use a background image to give it a more...woody look.
    But the problem is I don't understand shit about background images.  That's a problem indeed.
    </p>
    <p>Oh well, let's do a picture:</p>
    <br>
    <img id = "me" src ='IMG_1742.jpg' alt='my face'>
    <br>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function remove(){
            document.getElementsById("me").style.display = "none";

            //not sure why this doesn't work, but okay
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button"  OnClick="remove()">Remove Picture</button>


</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's `getElementById` not Element**s**.

Comment: Hahaha!  Wow!  Thanks.  So simple!  But one thing, before I was using getElementsByTagName and that didn't work either...in this case, Elements actually was correct, so why didn't it work?

Comment: @DennisMarkham getElementsByTagName returns an array, so you must access the element you want from the returned array first.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw gave you perfect explanation. =)

Answer (score 0):

You had an additional "s". Try with:
`document.getElementById("me")`

Answer (score 0):

// here is the answer. you wrote the wrong word.
put this code document.getElementById("me").style.display = "none"; to replace your code, the wrong word is getElementById  not getElementsById. got it?

Comment: read this for format your code .
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks